# Is there a way to add a Windows classic treeview to a webpage?

Tags: html, treeview

I'm trying to create a website which uses a treeview for navigation. Is there a way to make a treeview that not only looks superficially like the windows classic treeview but actually behaves exactly like it, and which can be embedded in a webpage?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IRZus.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is! I'm so glad you asked; I just found this amazing tool the other day that might help you.

Assuming you have all the content downloaded to your computer, you can use [Snap2HTML](https://www.rlvision.com/snap2html/about.php) to create an HTML directory navigation for the site.

I have it setup with pre- and post-commit Git hooks to regenerate each time I commit files to my repository. The instructions for this tool are pretty easy to follow, but let me know if you have any issues.

You can also edit the HTML template to make it work a bit nicer for the specific layout of your site.

[image: Image of Snap2HTML in action]